# Php Mysql Составить запрос

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

всем привет!
У меня стоит opencart 2.3 Когда я захожу в аккаунт в таблице oc_customer есть столбец number с числом например 5 если отдельно вписать

это отдельный запрос
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `oc_customer` WHERE `number` = ? ");

Как сделать что бы в запросе подставлялось число с поля number авторизованного пользователя?

Спасибо!

Comment: <?php echo $customer_number; ?> Вот так вот выводит 5, нужно что бы и в запросе поставлялась 5

Comment: Так а дальше `prepare()` где код? Вы подготавливаете запрос, а где бинд данных и выполнение? На основе такого скудного вопроса, ответ трудно дать

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM oc_customer WHERE number = {$customer_number} ");
```

попробуйте так и не помешало бы описания побольше вашего вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что нужно!!!